# LWC wired function is not connecting with cooresponding Apex method

Tags: lightning-web-components

Why is the console.log statement returning "undefined" in the browser console?

When I call the Apex method from Anonymous Class, it returns the expected String.

---

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import getUsersPermissionSet 
  from '@salesforce/apex/EsrmHomePage_Ctrl.getUsersPermissionSet';

export default class EsrmHomePageNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  recordPageUrl;
  usersPermissionSet;
  @track isManager = false;

  @wire(getUsersPermissionSet) 
    wiredGetUsersPermissionSet({data, error}) {
    
    console.log('*** data', data);

    if (data) {
      this.usersPermissionSet = data;
    }
    if (this.usersPermissionSet) {
      if (this.usersPermissionSet.includes("Manager")){
        this.isManager = true;
      }
    }
  };
```

---

```
public with sharing class EsrmHomePage_Ctrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getUsersPermissionSet(){

      String usersMainPermissionSet;
      
      List<PermissionSetAssignment> usersPermissionSets = 
        [SELECT PermissionSet.Label 
         FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
         WHERE PermissionSet.Label like '%Technical Assessment%' 
         AND AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
      
      /* SysAdmins may have a Basic and Manager permissionset. 
       * All other ESRM users should only have one.*/
      if(usersPermissionSets != null) {
        if(usersPermissionSets.size() > 1) {
          for(PermissionSetAssignment permSet : usersPermissionSets) {
            String permSetLabel = permSet.PermissionSet.Label;
            
            if(permSetLabel.contains('Manager')) {
              usersMainPermissionSet = permSetLabel;
            }
          }
        } else {
          String permSetLabel = usersPermissionSets.get(0).PermissionSet.Label; 
          usersMainPermissionSet = permSetLabel;
        }
      }
      System.debug('*** usersMainPermissionSet: ' + usersMainPermissionSet);
      return usersMainPermissionSet;
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Just as FYI - similar to Caspar's answer to your previous [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350097/lwc-wired-isnt-calling-the-apex-controller), you really should handle/use the error returned by these calls - it would've told you the issue in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you to be able to use methods as wired, the Auraenabled method needs to be set as cacheable=True

`Auraenabled (cacheable=true)`

[Client-Side Caching of Apex Method Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching)